# On a holiday vs On holiday

Tags: articles

> I'm substituting for her while she's **on holiday**.
>
> I'm substituting for her while she's **on a holiday**.

Are these sentences both correct?
Are there any differences?

To me, both are the exactly the same....

I would like to know the difference of "on holiday" vs "on a holiday". If you add "a" in front of "holiday", does it make any difference?

Comment: In case this doesn't get reopened:  There is little if any difference.  "On holiday" is a more British expression.  Americans would say "on vacation".  "On a holiday" might be used if you then describe some details about the "holiday".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A holiday is a day on which work is suspended by law or custom:

> It's a good thing that we have a holiday today because everyone has a
>   hangover.

You may have to the work for someone who's either [on holiday](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on%20holiday) (enjoying leisure time away from work devoted to rest or pleasure) or has a [day off](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/off-day?q=day+off).

On **a** holiday no one works, as a rule.